# Programmatically create\define Spring Cloud Stream bindings and Function

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-function, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I am looking for a way programmatically to create Function and binding of function to existing Channel (Channel will be added)

Ideally would be in event "BindingCreatedEvent" to create additional Binding.

To extend, the bellow configuration works as expected, I need programmatically create same entities

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: functionForProcessor1function
    stream:
      function:
        bindings:
          functionForProcessor1-in-0: functionForProcessor1_subscribe
```

Why it needed?
For each channel that Bound Binder "Kafka1",
will need to consumer additional channel from other "Binder" - "Kafka2"

The use is Spring Boot 3.x+

I have tried to create new configuration in EnvironmentPostProcessor, and it worked as expected
Need still to check option to create Function and Bindings dynamically in runtime

Comment: If EPP works for you that's fine, but it certainly feels like you are doing something the framework was not designed for. yOu didn't really explain the business reason for it, you simply stated that "for each channel here i need channel there". That is not the requirement, rather a description of the solution which seems wrong.

Comment: the requirement is to consume same topic from few clusters, 
topic configuration must be dynamic, based on configuration done for "base" topic, 
to avoid properties file update for secondary clusters

Comment: The "topic configuration must be dynamic, based on . . ." is not a requirement. That is a proposed solution and you are asking how to implement it. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?